# You need to pass a model name to the store's modelFor method

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have problem with making hasMany <=> belongTo relationship to work.

I have `articles/show` view, when I try to list article's comments but I keep recieving the error pointed in the title.

It's something with belongsTo: `DS.belongsTo('article')` but I couldn't figure out what it is.

**Here are my files.**

*routes/articles/show.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import RSVP from 'rsvp';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return RSVP.hash({
      article: this.store.find("article", params.id),
      comments: this.store.query('comment', { articleId: params.id })
    });
  }
});
```

*controllers/articles/show.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { computed: { alias, readOnly } } = Ember;

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  article: alias('model.article'),
  comments: alias('model.comments'),
  length: readOnly('comments.length')
});
```

*templates/articles/show.hbs*

```
<h3>Comments ({{comments.length}})</h3>
{{#each comments as |comment|}}
  <p>Author: {{comment.user.name}}</p>
  <p>Somebody said: {{comment.body}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

*adapters/comment.js*

```
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';
export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({});
```

*serializers/comment.js*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    user: { embedded: 'always' },
    article: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});
```

serializers/article.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    comments: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});
```

models/article.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

const { attr, hasMany } = DS;
const { computed: { gt } } = Ember;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title:        attr('string'),
  content:      attr('string'),

  authorName:   attr('string'),
  authorAvatar: attr('string'),
  authorUrl:    attr('string'),

  comments:     hasMany('comment', {async: true}),

  hasAvatar: gt('authorAvatar.length', 0)
});
```

**Edit:**

I added here the code for comment model as asked in the comments.

models/comment.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

const { belongsTo, attr } = DS;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  article: belongsTo(),
  user: belongsTo(),

  body: attr('string')
});
```

**And here is stacktrace from inspector:**

```
ember.debug.js:16905 Assertion Failed: You need to pass a model name to the store's modelFor method
Error
    at assert (http://ffl.com:8000/assets/vendor.js:16268:13)
    at Object.assert (http://ffl.com:8000/assets/vendor.js:27196:34)
    at assert (http://ffl.com:8000/assets/vendor.js:135212:37)
    at Class.modelFor (http://ffl.com:8000/assets/vendor.js:145201:41)
    at Class._internalModelForId (http://ffl.com:8000/assets/vendor.js:144337:29)
    at Class._pushResourceIdentifier (http://ffl.com:8000/assets/vendor.js:145716:19)
    at BelongsToRelationship.updateData (http://ffl.com:8000/assets/vendor.js:142394:36)
    at BelongsToRelationship.push (http://ffl.com:8000/assets/vendor.js:142976:14)
    at http://ffl.com:8000/assets/vendor.js:145795:20
    at http://ffl.com:8000/assets/vendor.js:141943:18
defaultDispatch @   ember.debug.js:16905
dispatchError   @   ember.debug.js:16888
onerrorDefault  @   ember.debug.js:30389
trigger @   ember.debug.js:57833
(anonymous) @   ember.debug.js:58717
invoke  @   ember.debug.js:339
flush   @   ember.debug.js:407
flush   @   ember.debug.js:531
end @   ember.debug.js:601
run @   ember.debug.js:724
join    @   ember.debug.js:746
run.join    @   ember.debug.js:21556
hash.success    @   rest.js:954
fire    @   jquery.js:3305
fireWith    @   jquery.js:3435
done    @   jquery.js:9242
(anonymous) @   jquery.js:9484
```

Comment: Do you have code, which call `modelFor` method with empty arguments ?. Have you defined comment model ?. if so post that one also ?. if possible inlcude stack trace for this assertion error. to identify which method is triggering `modelFor`. latest version `find` is private method.

Comment: @kumkanillam I added both as you requested. Hope that will help.

Comment: Don't we need to mention model name in belongsTo relationship, like   `article: belongsTo('article')` and  `user: belongsTo('user`)`  for comment model. I am not sure about this. if it doesn't help you then you may need to walk through server response data format.

Comment: I did mention it ealier (nothing changed), but if names matches the relationship, there is no need for that.

Comment: I don't have the `modelFor` call in the whole code. BTW: I here you can view the whole source code of this project. It's basic one. https://github.com/wilgoszpl/frontendflow-ember/tree/refactor-and-upgrade-ember

Comment: If you can provide response data you are getting from server, it would be easy for others to answer. my guess is it's not following standard format for REST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your issue and repo. The problem was just with comment serializer in Ember.js. It should be:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    article: { embedded: 'always' },
    user: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I cloned your project branch refactor-and-upgrade-ember  but mirage is not done. So I looked at the code

```
headTags() {
  let article = this.modelFor(this.routeName);
}
```

This is in routes articles show ,can you try and remove it and try.

Comment: Indeed but even after removing that, this error appears - when I prepared the question, I removed those tags to be sure - this is why I mentioned in the comments above, that I didn't have `modelFor` - but I appreciate your effort, thanks!